# Autowiring JdbcTemplate vs Datasource?

Tags: spring-jdbc

Which would be the right/better practice when implementing non-jpa/orm DAO layers?

```java
@Repository
public class SampleDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public SampleDao(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    // --- OR ---

    public SampleDao(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Spring Boot application I'd generally recommend injecting `JdbcOperations` rather than injecting the `JdbcTemplate` or creating a new `JdbcTemplate` instance from the `DataSource`. The `JdbcOperations` interface is implemented by the auto-configured `JdbcTemplate`.

The reasons are as follows:

- The bean is already defined, so there's one less object instance
- `JdbcOperations` doesn't surface any setters so you can't accidentally change things on the shared singleton bean
- You can use `spring.jdbc.template...` application properties to configure it
- It's easier to mock than `DataSource` if you need to do so for testing